# Cannot bind <Control-bracketleft>, <Control-bracketright> in tkinter.ttk.Notebook (Python 3.5.1)

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I want to provide users with multiple keybinds for tab traversal in a tkinter.ttk.Notebook object. I'm using the following code:

```
self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
self.notebook.enable_traversal()
self.notebook.bind('<Control-Key-Prior>', self.priorTab)
self.notebook.bind('<Control-Key-Next>', self.nextTab)
self.notebook.bind('<Control-bracketleft>', self.priorTab)
self.notebook.bind('<Control-bracketright>', self.nextTab)
```

enable_traversal() produces expected behavior, allowing Control-Shift-Tab and Control-Tab navigation. The  and  bindings also produce the desired result, allowing Control-PageUp and Control-PageDown navigation.

The third option, however, fails. I expected  and  to allow navigation via Control-[ and Control-], but they do nothing. I confirmed that the keysyms are correct by checking the appropriate Tk manpage, and the keysyms do not produce an error in the Python interpreter.

In my understanding, tkinter should not have any problem with two events bound to the same callback. Am I making a mistake somewhere, or are the bracket keys unsupported? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is probably nothing wrong with the bindings. If you bind to the notebook itself then it must have focus for the bindings to register ( select a tab to gain focus ). If you want the bindings to toggle the notebook tab no matter what has focus then bind to the top-level window ( in this example root )

Example Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def change_tab(delta):
    print("triggered")
    tabs = note.tabs()
    note.select( tabs[(tabs.index(note.select()) + delta) % len(tabs)] )

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(250, 250)

note = ttk.Notebook(root, height = 200, width = 200)
note.pack()
#note.enable_traversal()

for i in range(1, 6):
    note.add(tk.Frame(note), text = "Tab #%d" % i)

# Note requires focus for bindings to work
# Change to root for bindings to work anywhere in the app
note.bind('<Control-[>', lambda e: change_tab(-1))
note.bind('<Control-]>', lambda e: change_tab(1))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Found the problem. Even though no exception was raised, there was a problem in the callback function. Once that was fixed, everything worked as expected. The reason why I was confused was that the Notebook.enable_traversal() method provides two sets of bindings: Control-Tab and Control-Shift-Tab, as well as Control-PageUp and Control-PageDown. The second pair of bindings is undocumented in tkinter.ttk.